# Using state inside @ModuleAction of vuex-module-decorators

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3, vuex-modules, vuex-module-decorators

When trying to access the baseUrl set in the state of a module, I get the typescript error: `Property 'baseUrl' does not exist on type 'ThisType<any> | (() => ThisType<any>)'.`

This is my .ts file:

```
import { Module, MutationAction, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import axios from 'axios';

@Module({ namespaced: true, name: 'countriesStore' })
export default class CountriesStore extends VuexModule {
  countries: unknown = {}
  baseUrl = "/api/countries"

  @MutationAction
  async getCountries(): Promise<unknown> {
    const countries = await axios.get(this.state.baseUrl)
    return { countries }
  }
}
```

What I want is to be able to reach a value set for the whole class, but this gives a typescript error. I can log the baseUrl when I log `this.state.baseUrl`, but the error lets the build fail. I can type the state as any, like `(this.state as any).baseUrl`, but this I also something I would like to prevent. Typescript lets me do `this.baseUrl`, but this returns `undefined`. Is there a way to reach the state without typing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are setting up your Vuex store.
But it sounds like you are creating a module and need to call it via that. It looks like you setup the module correctly.
Using Vue2js and Vuex3 (important since deprecated) this can be done like:

```
this.$store.state.countriesStore.baseUrl
```

It sounds like you are trying to access the value without mentioning the module. If you want to commit or modify the url later, a mutation is needed:

```
  @Mutation
  setBaseUrl(url: string) {
    this.baseUrl = url
  }

// to invoke, use:
this.$store.commit('countriesStore/baseUrl', 'https://new-url-here.com')
```

I am not sure if that resolves or answers your question, per say. But I hope it helps.